# What trim technique do you use to work around plumbing - behind toilet?

Tags: plumbing, woodworking, trim, trim-carpentry

I have 8" trim I am laying down on a house.    In the bathroom - wood floors - the area behind the toilet is kind of perplexing because I will need to take the toilet up for a 6 foot board to get behind it...  whatever fine.

The bigger challenge is the water line to the toilet about 5" up in the middle of this board.    What is the proper technique for something like this?

And yes normally I would just notch a rectangle out of the top of the board but I have been fancying this house up so figured there is probably a nicer way of doing it.

Comment: If you do the measurements right, turn off the water before the line to the toilet and just make a hole to fit the pipe, no notches.  It will probably mean removing the shut off valve also to fit the trim onto the pipe.  Second way is to use a very fine blade saw(hand), maybe a coping saw to cut a notch and add the top section back, with some glue.

Comment: I've seen plenty of cases where the trim just stops behind the toilet. Nobody ever notices unless they are removing the toilet.

Comment: cut the board in half where the pipe comes out of the wall ... cut a notches in the board ends for the pipe to pass through

Answer (score 2):

Most reasonable people consider taking up the toilet to install a trim board that only people who have fallen in the bathroom and can't get up will ever examine closely to be a bit over the top. Put a joint in where the pipe comes through the trim, drill a hole for your pipe centered on the joint, done, easy. Perhaps a nice escutcheon around the pipe.

If you want the hard way, remove the valve from the pipe and drill a hole in the trim board, or remove the pipe from the wall and drill a hole in the trim board.

The fancy way is a tile baseboard (or cove base trim.)

Comment: I thought that if you forgot to bring reading material, the only other choice is to look for trim mistakes.

Comment: Put in a couple of USB chargers and the modern folks always have reading material. I presume you must carry a mirror for checking that board behind the "throne" while using it?

Comment: I've considered a plynth but unless I put something huge huge in then the cover for the plumbing will extend past the top of the plynth.   The fact that half of it is over makes it trickier.    Tile isn't an option since there isn't tile in the entire bathroom.

Comment: I won't DV, but spare a thought for the people on the floor. They need quality too! In seriousness, if this was my house, I'd pull the toilet in a heartbeat; otherwise I'd always know there was hackery back there.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - only a psycho can knowingly mess something like that up.    That is the only thing you will think about in the spot you are at 20 minutes a day.